# How to reference an object's attribute as both obj and attribute are variables?

Tags: python, django

I have code as below:

```
 {% for entry in qs %}
 {% for field_name in field_names %}
        <span>{{entry.field_name}}</span>
 {%endfor%}
 {%endfor%}
```

But nothing will show up inside span tag. Then I change back to

```
 {{entry.name}}
```

which "name" is a property of every entry. Then the correct value shows up.

Why is that? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Just register a new template tag getattr()

```
import re
from django import template
from django.conf import settings

numeric_test = re.compile("^\d+$")
register = template.Library()

# @register.getattribute
def getattribute(value, arg):
    """Gets an attribute of an object dynamically from a string name"""

    if hasattr(value, str(arg)):
        return getattr(value, arg)
    elif hasattr(value, 'has_key') and value.has_key(arg):
        return value[arg]
    elif numeric_test.match(str(arg)) and len(value) > int(arg):
       return value[int(arg)]
    else:
       return settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID

register.filter('getattribute', getattribute)
```

And in template

```
{% load getattribute %}

<span>{{entry|getattribute:field_name}}</span>
```